# OData DataServiceContext query without DataServiceKey attribute

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services

On the server side I have an Entity Framework DbContext `NorthwindContext` and an `System.Data.DataService<NorthwindContext>`

My client needs to query the dataservice. I am able to retrive data with

```
var uriString = "http://localhost:8888/northwind.svc";
var context = new DataServiceContext(new Uri(uriString));
var query = context.CreateQuery<orders>("orders");
var result = query.ToList();
```

Ok so far this works. I don't use the visual studio tool chain for client proxy / class generation but create my own "copy" of the orders class which looks like this

```
[DataServiceKey("OrderID")]
public partial class orders
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This only works because I specified the DataServiceKey attribute. If I don't do that, I get an `DataServiceQueryException`

DataServiceKey is from `Microsoft.Data.Service.Client` which is referenced by my main assembly my model `orders` is in a seperate assembly where I don't want to have a reference to `Microsoft.Data.Service.Client`

Is it possible to use my query without needing to decorate my class with `DataServiceKey` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove DataServiceKey from the entity you declare.

•Entity keys - each data class that is an entity type must have a key property. This property is attributed with the DataServiceKeyAttribute attribute ([DataServiceKeyAttribute]).

Link:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723653(v=vs.113).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723653%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Regards
Kajal

Answer (score 0):

There are alternate data annotations when creating your own data model for OData.
See the [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) and (depending on the framework version) [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However, I've used these when creating my WCF DataService using `DbContext`, not `DataServiceContext` for the underlying model.